# How to change /usr/libexec/java_home default return path on Mac10.12

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I've installed 2 versions (1.8r171 and 1.8r151) of java, and I want to make r151 as default java. However, even if I set the `JAVA_HOME` env, `java -version` works fine, but `java_home` always return the old r171 version. Why? How can I change `

```
###### two version listed by java_home #######
[^_^ 09:48 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines] /usr/libexec/java_home  -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_151, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

###### export to use r151 ###########
[^_^ 09:48 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines] export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

###### works for java -version #######
[^_^ 09:48 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines] java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

###### BUT java_home still points to r171 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ######
[^_^ 09:49 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines] /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Are you using Bash command line? Also is it possible for you to find and show your .bashrc file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using bash. My bashrc is a little bit large, so I grep `java`  and only get ``export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"``. The problem still exists if I remove this line